# http error 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I'm creating an ASP.NET 4.5 website using visual studio 2013, I'm only new to visual studio and asp so I just need a little help.

I've created a web forms project and it runs, my homepage loads up and works fine but when I try to navigate to the registration, login and about template pages in visual studio I get a 404 error. It also says

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Should the pages not already be connected to the server? Or is there something I have to do?

About:

```
 Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="StudentMS.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
    <h3>Your application description page.</h3>
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
</asp:Content>
```

siteMaster:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="StudentMS.SiteMaster" %>

<asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions" />
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>

                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />    
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">National College of Ireland (SMS)</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any reason you need webforms over MVC?  The latter is generally much easier to learn and understand and work with

Comment: For college, It was a requirement for the project to be web forms. So have any idea how to get the pages working? Iv'e been at it for the last hour.

Comment: Show your code please...

Comment: I added the site master the the about page that won't show, I can more code from another file if you have an idea where the problem is

Comment: I guess URL routing isn't configured yet or who knows

Comment: @Jonesy well that's clearly your opinion.

Comment: Are you able to confirm that you're including the `.aspx` extension for the page in your URL when navigating to say registration etc?